# How to see the templated values in airflow?

Tags: airflow

When I do something like:

```
some_value = "{{ dag_run.get_task_instance('start').start_date }}"
print(f"some interpolated value: {some_value}")
```

I see this in the airflow logs:

```
some interpolated value: {{ dag_run.get_task_instance('start').start_date }}
```

but not the actual value itself. How can I easily see what the value is?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the DAG task run comes through as `kwargs` (before 1.10.12 you needed to add `provide_context`, but all context is provided after version 2).

To get something out of `kwargs`, do something like this in your python callable:

```
run_id = kwargs['run_id']
print(f'run_id = {run_id}')
```

**Additional info:**

To get the kwargs out, add them to your callable, so:

```
def my_func(**kwargs):
    run_id = kwargs['run_id']
    print(f'run_id = {run_id}')
```

And just call this from your DAG task like:

```
my_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='my_task'
    , dag=dag
    , python_callable=my_func)
```

I'm not sure what your current code structure is because you haven't provided more info I'm afraid.

Comment: so in my example, what would I pull out of kwargs?

Comment: @Jwan622 I've updated the answer with more information, please check again.